ProxyPass issue
I would need some guidance or someone to point me to a direction on how can this be done.
This is my directory structure :
/var/www

live_website
new_website

right now abc.com points to the 'live_website' folder. What i'll need to do is i'll need to point the live website to 'new_website' folder BUT if users go to certain urls such as abc.com/jp/  then it will be served by the 'live_website' folder instead of the 'new_website' folder.
The server is a nginx server right now and I am not sure what should i do. both sites are using wordpress if it matters.

Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your title now is just the useless word issue, which is vague and meaningless. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].

Like this:
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  abc.com;
  
  index index.html;
  
  location /jp {
    alias /var/www/live_website;
  }
  
  location / {
    root /var/www/new_website;
  }
}

